# How do i flip a highchart?

Tags: highcharts

How can i flip the chart so it would start from right to left ?

see the below example: ( i flipped the picture )

---

[image: example]

Comment: you want to flip only the bars or also the characters?

Answer (score 0):

you can flip xAxis or yAxis with out flipping labels like this:

```
xAxis: {
    reversed: true  
},
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/WzVh4/547/)

Answer (score 0):

Apart from reversed option, you should also use rtl parameter for legend. 
http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#legend.rtl